# A blank output when attempting to draw a complex valued function

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, pst-func

I want to plot

[image]

with the following output:

[image]

However, my code below

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-func}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-10,-10)(10,10)
    \def\e{2.71828182846}
    \psplotImp[linecolor=red,algebraic](-3,-3)(3,3){%
        (\e)^(8*x*y*(x^2-y^2)) + 1/((\e)^(8*x*y*(x^2-y^2))) + 2*cos(2*(x^4)+2*(y^4)-12*(x^2)*(y^2))-4}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

produces a blank page.

### Question

- First, how to fix the blank page?
- Can PSTricks draw `abs(cos((x+iy)^4))-1` directly?
- For the existing answers, the outputs are slightly different near the origin. How to fix this problem as well?

Comment: You are satisfied with the missing dots around the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to control the exponent, PostScript knows only single precision for floating point operations. For example e^100 is not possible. The check is easier on PostScript level, the reason why I do not use the algebraic option.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.9,-2.9)(2.9,2.9)
    \psplotImp[linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.1](-3,-3)(3,3){%
        /x2 x dup mul def /x4 x2 dup mul def 
        /y2 y dup mul def /y4 y2 dup mul def 
        /xy x y mul def
        8 xy mul x2 y2 sub mul dup abs 70 lt % abs(exponent) < 70? 
          { Euler exch exp }  % yes, then build the bower
          { 0 gt { 1e30 }{ 1e-30 } ifelse } ifelse
        dup 1 exch div
        2 x4 mul 2 y4 mul add 
           12 x2 mul y2 mul sub RadtoDeg cos 2 mul 4 sub
        add add }
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you see at the center? Why the Asymptote has the output that is differ from PSTricks's output?

Comment: With `pst-tools` you have all PostScript operators for complex numbers. A complex number must be saved as an array `[a b]` then you can do something like `[1 3] cxsqr` and you'll get `[a²-b²  2ab]`. Look into the `pst-tools.pro`

Comment: The dots around the origin `(0,0)` are missing in my and your outputs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no discontinuity in PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-func}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psplotImp[linecolor=red,algebraic,stepFactor=0.1](-2,-2)(2,2){%
        Euler^(8*x*y*(x^2-y^2)) + 1/(Euler^(8*x*y*(x^2-y^2))) + 2*cos(2*(x^4)+2*(y^4)-12*(x^2)*(y^2))-4}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for values > abs(2)